# Manage checkbox created by jquery with C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

Here is my problem :

I want to manage the state of a checkbox in a webform page using visual studio 2010 to which i have reduced the code to the strict minimum for you to better understand my problem.

In order to get the state of my checkbox dynamically created i have tried severals things :

- At the beginning my wish was simply : get the state of my checkbox in code-behing which is for my case the c# but i quickly realised that i needed to put the attribute runat="server" to the spans that contains the state of my checkbox
- So i have changed the dynamic declaration of the spans and i have added the attributes "id" and "runat" to each of the two spans. After, these attributes were visible in the code source when the page is generated but i still couldn't manage them in the code-behind
- I finally tried to use the DOM function : `getElementById` but when i check with the debugger, the variable is always `null`

In fact i think i just need to act when the page is fully loaded but i don't know how.

**I just need to know if my checkbox is on or off.**

Here is the body content :

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <div class="checkbox1" id="CB1">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1"/>
          </div>     
    </form>   

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {     

            $('input[type=checkbox]').switchButton({
                button_width: 10,
                labels_placement: "left",
                height: 22,
                width: 50
            });

        })        
    </script>
</body>
```

The jquery script is there : [Jquery](https://github.com/olance/jQuery-switchButton/blob/master/jquery.switchButton.js)

The css for the particular checkbox is there : [Css](https://github.com/olance/jQuery-switchButton/blob/master/jquery.switchButton.css)

Let me know how to make this work.

Comment: Hi, could you provide your try with `GetElementById`? btw, don't you need a `;` after width: 50?

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, Here is the [Screenshot](http://imageshack.com/a/img849/9494/taiu.png) and no, i don't need a `;` after width because these are only parameters of switchButton managed by jQuery

Comment: Ok, next time try [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/inline-links-in-comments) for inline link in comment because your link lead to an error, got to remove the last `]` in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switchButton` (which I've developed) doesn't delete or modify the initial checkbox input you apply the plugin to...

So I suggest you create your checkbox just like you would in any other project and get its state through C# code...

I guess that's what other people have suggested here already.

Comment: Finally it's **working**, i didn't understood that your switchButton doesn't modify the initial checkbox input. I have tried too many things for make this example out but i didn't analyse correctly the switch button behavior
So the solution is simply to put an `<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />` instead of a simple `<input type="checkbox" value="1"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Possible you need to do an Async Postback to your code behind Updating the Control Tree of your Page with the newly added Element. Otherwise C# has no way of knowing you add an element with jQuery.

The code should look like that

```
    TextBox TitleTxtBox = new TextBox();
    TitleTxtBox.ID = "TitleTxtBox";

    this.Controls.Add(TitleTxtBox);
```

There is an article here that will help:

http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/30/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-3_2900_.aspx

Another possible solution might be to request Request.Form to get the newly added element but i'm not sure if it works. Can't check it right now.

```
  if (Request.Form["checkboxName"] != null && Request.Form["checkboxName"] == "on")
        {
            Response.Write("This checkbox is selected");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("This checkbox is not selected");
        }
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1440174.aspx

Hope the above will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the checkbox as asp:checkbox then on client side using clientID call `switchButton` function on it.

If you don't know how many checkboxes you will need, then you can create the checkboxes with name attribute and on server side access it like this `Request["checkBoxName"]`.

You can do something like this to create many checkboxes and get their values easily:

```
Dictionary<string, bool> data = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
foreach (var item in Request.Params)
{
    //code_chkId_001, true
    if (item != null && item.ToString().StartsWith("code_"))
    {
        data.Add(item.ToString().Replace("code_", "")/*chkId_001*/ ,
                Convert.ToBoolean(Request[item.ToString()]) /*true*/); 
//you have to check here, if it's "on" instead of "true" ToBoolean will break.
    }
}
```

I know this is like a hack, but I hate Asp.Net's postback and mainly use AJAX. Hope it helps.